# JSP, jquery and HTML : use form post data in ajax call.

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Here is what I want to do (this is the way I am doing, if there is any better way please suggest).

Page 1 (jsp) : accept form data. jquery binds the submit for form button. validates input and then submits.

Page 2  (jsp) : static HTML is loaded. Now, using the data submitted as part of form on page1, I want to make a ajax call (jquery) which will populate page2 dynamic part.

```
<% out.println(request.getParameter("someparam"));%>
```

above doesnt work inside script tag.

so one option : get these form variables in the jsp. set some hidden variables and then in jquery process those form variable.

Any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but seems like you're making an AJAX call to a JSP page and displaying the response/HTML. With the out.println, you seem to be printing a request param of the AJAX call into a script tag within the HTML. It's difficult to say what's wrong without sample code.

Since you're looking for a better alternative to this, I would highly recommend using a client-side templating engine and exchanging only data (json, xml) with the server-side. This would help reduce data transfered as well as improve responsiveness of the front-end.

Consider using [Backbone](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/) or [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), and refactoring the server-side to exchange data/JSON with the browser.